# Spark, YARN, and AWS EMR: INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 11, (reason: Due to executor failures all available node

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have an AWS EMR cluster running Spark 2.4.4. I'm running a monthly data conversion process with Pyspark, and have never had an issue with it, but today I'm hitting a new error I've never seen before:

```
INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 11, (reason: Due to executor failures all available nodes are blacklisted)
```

Has anyone seen this error and point to why it might be happening?

Here's a larger snippet of my stderr file:

```
20/10/13 00:33:12 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 502 executors.
20/10/13 00:33:15 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-45-56.ec2.internal to RUNNING
20/10/13 00:33:15 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Running) for host ip-XXX-31-45-56.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:33:52 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 501 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:33:52 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 501 executors.
20/10/13 00:34:09 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 500 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:34:09 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 500 executors.
20/10/13 00:34:39 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 499 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:34:39 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 499 executors.
20/10/13 00:34:55 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 498 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:34:55 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 498 executors.
20/10/13 00:35:15 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 497 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:35:15 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 497 executors.
20/10/13 00:35:34 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 496 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:35:34 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 496 executors.
20/10/13 00:35:58 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 495 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:35:58 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 495 executors.
20/10/13 00:36:07 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 494 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:36:07 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 494 executors.
20/10/13 00:36:20 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 493 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:36:20 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 493 executors.
20/10/13 00:36:24 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 492 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:36:24 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 492 executors.
20/10/13 00:36:31 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 491 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:36:31 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 491 executors.
20/10/13 00:36:37 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 490 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:36:37 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 490 executors.
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-45-21.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONING
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioning(20)) for host ip-XXX-31-45-21.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-39-56.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-39-56.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-47-237.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONING
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioning(20)) for host ip-XXX-31-47-237.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONING
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioning(20)) for host ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-40-98.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONING
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioning(20)) for host ip-XXX-31-40-98.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-35-249.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONING
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioning(20)) for host ip-XXX-31-35-249.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-36-204.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONING
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioning(20)) for host ip-XXX-31-36-204.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-45-56.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONING
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioning(20)) for host ip-XXX-31-45-56.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-32-155.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONING
20/10/13 00:36:38 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioning(20)) for host ip-XXX-31-32-155.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-45-21.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-45-21.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-47-237.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-47-237.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-40-98.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-40-98.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-35-249.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-35-249.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-36-204.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-36-204.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-45-56.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-45-56.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-32-155.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:36:40 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-32-155.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:36:42 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 489 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:36:42 INFO YarnAllocatorBlacklistTracker: adding nodes to YARN application master's blacklist: List(ip-XXX-31-32-155.ec2.internal, ip-XXX-31-35-249.ec2.internal, ip-XXX-31-36-204.ec2.internal, ip-XXX-31-40-98.ec2.internal, ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ec2.internal, ip-XXX-31-45-21.ec2.internal, ip-XXX-31-45-56.ec2.internal, ip-XXX-31-47-237.ec2.internal)
20/10/13 00:36:42 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 489 executors.
20/10/13 00:36:50 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 488 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:36:50 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 488 executors.
20/10/13 00:37:00 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 487 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:37:00 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 487 executors.
20/10/13 00:37:07 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 486 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:37:07 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 486 executors.
20/10/13 00:37:11 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 485 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:37:11 INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 1 executor container(s) to have a new desired total 485 executors.
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-39-64.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-39-64.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-35-183.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-35-183.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-32-30.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-32-30.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-42-148.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-42-148.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-47-172.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-47-172.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-45-171.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-45-171.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-40-251.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-40-251.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Yarn node state updated for host ip-XXX-31-47-53.ec2.internal to DECOMMISSIONED
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Detected updated state Some(Decommissioned) for host ip-XXX-31-47-53.ec2.internal
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 484 executor(s).
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 11, (reason: Due to executor failures all available nodes are blacklisted)
20/10/13 00:37:17 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Comment: I have received a similar error recently, were you running your workload on Spot Instances?